# Jquery remove divs already in page when adding data from AJAX response

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery.get("ajax.php", function(data)
    {
        prev = $("#newsfeed").html(); //Remember what was in the newsfeed
        $(data).find("div[id^='feed']").each(function() //Find every div starting with feed in AJAX response
            {
                alert('#' + $(this).attr("id")); //Works fine
                $('#' + $(this).attr("id")).remove(); //Remove any existing div with same id - Not working
             });
        $("#newsfeed").html(data + prev); //Append the AJAX response to the top of the page
    });
```

Please help, I'm relativly new to Jquery and don't have a clue what's going wrong.

Comment: What's the output of `alert('#' + $(this).attr("id").length);`? You can shorthand `$('#' + $(this).attr("id")).remove();` to `$(this).remove()`

Comment: @mattytommo $(this) is the new element, the old one is part of the DOM and needs to be removed.

Comment: @KevinB Ah, but it's not clear what he wants to remove :)

Comment: @mattytommo - From the question: `//Remove any existing div with same id - Not working`

Comment: @KevinB Ah missed that, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll do one better. It looks like you are removing data and then adding it back later.

If you just prepend to html, the new data will go on the top.

```
$("#newsfeed").prepend(data);
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. That seems really obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

## one option

```
var $newsfeed = $("#newsfeed");
var prev = $newsfeed.html();
$newsfeed.load("ajax.php").append(prev);
```

## another option

```
//register a clean event that will look for all ids that start with 'feed'
//do not use '#feed***' selector, as it will the ID that it finds first, and then stop.
       $("#newsfeed").on({"cleanIds":function(event){
//grab the divs
          $(event.data.selector,"#newsfeed").each(function(index,elem){
//remove the id attribute altogether, or come up with a better way to renumber them
//rip out the ID and throw it into the class for storage / usage
          $(this).addClass($(this).attr("id")).removeAttr("id");
       });
        },null,{selector:"div[id^='feed']"}});

    $.get("ajax.php", function(data){
//prepend your stuff, then trigger the clean event.
       $("#newsfeed").prepend(data).trigger("cleanIds");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may by running into issues with having multiple elements with the same ID (which is not allowed).

Try setting a context for the remove call like this

`$('#' + $(this).attr('id'), 'body').remove( );`

which should differentiate it from the element that you got back from your AJAX call.

This is completely untested and a shot in the dark...

Comment: @Benjamin if duplicate IDs for the same element was the case, your code would in fact work (I tested it) :)